# Angular $resource doesn't call get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

Just trying to get a very simple REST get call to work using angularjs `$resource` service.  The API is never called.  Here is the code:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])
.service('tourRepository', function ($resource) {
    this.get = function (id) {
        alert('tourRepositoryCalled for id ' + id + '!');  // this is called
        var tour = $resource('/api/tour/:tourid', { tourId: '@id' });
        return tour.get({ tourId: id }, function () {
            alert('tour api called.');  // THIS NEVER IS
        });
    }
```

If I use a browser and go to /api/tour/3, it works.  What am I doing wrong here?  I thought $resource calls could be much easier, for example like below, but I am following angularjs documentation.

Ideally:

```
$scope.tour = $resource.get('/api/tour/' + id);   // why wouldn't this work?
```

All that I want to do is call a simple REST service and assign the results to my $scope.tour object.  Since I'm in a service though (my 'repository') I don't have access to the $scope.  What's the best way to go about this?  When I change the code to below the API is getting hit.

```
        var tour = $resource('/api/tour/:tourid');
        var theTour = tour.get({ tourid: id });
        alert(theTour.id);
```

Comment: If you open chrome developer tools, how things are looking at the network tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple models you can use $http instead of $resource

```
$http.get('/api/tour/' + id).success(function (tour) {
  $scope.tour = tour;
```

});

$resource is a service for creating javascript classes (ActiveRecord style).

```
var Tour = $resource(...) // capital T
var tour1 = Tour.get()
```

Although slightly confusing, your code should work. does the ajax request take place? and does it return a valid response?

Comment: The ajax request doesn't happen.  When I change the code to use the tour object in the service, it does happen.

Comment: the $http.get().success() method was the easiest way to implement this.  I don't fully understand resource or why you would use it.  Supposedly more powerful for REST but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Once the get request is completed the returned object is filled with the data got from the response, there's no callback in the `$resource`'s `get` method.

`$resource` is useful when you attach the object which is returned by the call to a scope instance. In this case when the object is resolved and the digest loop is called the view is being automatically updated.

If you need a callback you can use:

```
$http.get('/api/tour/' + id)
.then(function (tour) {
    $scope.tour = tour;
});
```

By using your services you can:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, tourRepository) {
  $scope.tour = tourRepository.get(ID_OF_THE_TOUR);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, assign the result to my $scope.tour.  I thought I could do it all with $resource at a higher level than $http (so not have to deal with promises)

Comment: Ok, great. I updated my answer in order to reflect your question. Please, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I've implemented my callback using your recommendation on $http.get..  I find $resource to be incredibly confusing and couldn't get it to work.. this was simple and easy.  I think .success is probably the correct method to use though (rather than .then), isn't it?

Comment: Both are true, since the result returned by `$http.get` is promise. Checkout http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `ngResource` module in your app('app.services') dependencies. The spelling of `tourid` in the url must be `tourId`

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
.service('tourRepository', function ($resource) {
    this.get = function (id) {
        alert('tourRepositoryCalled for id ' + id + '!');
        var tour = $resource('/api/tour/:tourId', { tourId: '@id' });
        return tour.get({ tourId: id }, function () {
            alert('tour api called.'); 
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is not true.  I have the 'ngResource' dependency on my app declaration and it is being hit in the right circumstances (see my question edit)

Comment: I do not see any line like `angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])` in your code.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. You have spelling mistake in tourid in url.

Comment: Here is my app declaration:
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'app.filters', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.controllers', 'ngResource'])